# Как сократить участок кода JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Есть участок кода JSP страницы, использующий запросы из spring message:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.containsValue('add')}">
        <spring:message code="meal.create"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <spring:message code="meal.edit"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Помогите переписать в тернарный оператор; я пока не понял как сделать одни скобки внутри других, чтобы это сократить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<spring:message code="meal.${param.containsValue('add')? 'create' : 'edit'}"/>
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало!